# Keras: Validation data not showing accuracy

Tags: python, validation, keras, neural-network, lstm

I built an algorithm in Python for data sets classification with Keras. It's a very simple LSTM network with 1 input layer, 1 hidden layer (LSTM) and 1 dense output layer.

My data consists of some analog measurements: 63 sets for training and 36 sets for testing, each set having 3 channels with 19200 samples each channel, so (following what I understood reading the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/)) the input shape I needed was x = (63,19200,3) and y = (36,19200,3). (If you want some additional information about the type of data, I can explain more.)

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras import initializers
from keras import optimizers

# Fix random seed for reproducibility.
np.random.seed(1)

# Loading data (shapes: X_test (36,19200,3), y_test (36,3), X_train (63,19200,3), y_train (63,3))
(X_test, y_test), (X_train, y_train) = np.load('path.npy',allow_pickle=True)
data = [(X_test, y_test), (X_train, y_train)]

# Manually separating the validation data.
x_val = X_train[-10:]
y_val = y_train[-10:]
X_train = X_train[:-10]
y_train = y_train[:-10]

# Creating model.
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(19200,3)))
model.add(LSTM(50, name = 'LSTM', activation='tanh',recurrent_activation='tanh', kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=1), bias_initializer=initializers.zeros()))
model.add(Dense(1, name = 'Saida', activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=1), bias_initializer=initializers.zeros()))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=12, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

# Final evaluation of the model.
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Very simple, but not that organized, still working on that.

And for this run, the results are:

```
Model: "sequential_8"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
LSTM (LSTM)                  (None, 50)                10800     
_________________________________________________________________
Saida (Dense)                (None, 1)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 10,851
Trainable params: 10,851
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Epoch 1/20
5/5 [==============================] - 17s 3s/step - loss: 0.6866 - accuracy: 0.6792 - val_loss: 0.6956 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/20
5/5 [==============================] - 20s 4s/step - loss: 0.6814 - accuracy: 0.8113 - val_loss: 0.6979 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/20
5/5 [==============================] - 21s 4s/step - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.7925 - val_loss: 0.7002 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/20
5/5 [==============================] - 24s 5s/step - loss: 0.6810 - accuracy: 0.7925 - val_loss: 0.7025 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/20
5/5 [==============================] - 25s 5s/step - loss: 0.6828 - accuracy: 0.7925 - val_loss: 0.7048 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/20
5/5 [==============================] - 24s 5s/step - loss: 0.6703 - accuracy: 0.8302 - val_loss: 0.7072 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/20
5/5 [==============================] - 24s 5s/step - loss: 0.6787 - accuracy: 0.7925 - val_loss: 0.7095 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/20
5/5 [==============================] - 26s 5s/step - loss: 0.6963 - accuracy: 0.7547 - val_loss: 0.7117 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/20
5/5 [==============================] - 25s 5s/step - loss: 0.6776 - accuracy: 0.7925 - val_loss: 0.7141 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/20
5/5 [==============================] - 25s 5s/step - loss: 0.6640 - accuracy: 0.8302 - val_loss: 0.7164 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/20
5/5 [==============================] - 24s 5s/step - loss: 0.6626 - accuracy: 0.8491 - val_loss: 0.7187 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/20
5/5 [==============================] - 24s 5s/step - loss: 0.6504 - accuracy: 0.8491 - val_loss: 0.7210 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/20
5/5 [==============================] - 24s 5s/step - loss: 0.6729 - accuracy: 0.7925 - val_loss: 0.7233 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/20
5/5 [==============================] - 24s 5s/step - loss: 0.6602 - accuracy: 0.8302 - val_loss: 0.7257 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/20
5/5 [==============================] - 25s 5s/step - loss: 0.6857 - accuracy: 0.7547 - val_loss: 0.7281 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 16/20
5/5 [==============================] - 23s 5s/step - loss: 0.6630 - accuracy: 0.8113 - val_loss: 0.7305 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 17/20
5/5 [==============================] - 25s 5s/step - loss: 0.6633 - accuracy: 0.7925 - val_loss: 0.7328 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 18/20
5/5 [==============================] - 24s 5s/step - loss: 0.6600 - accuracy: 0.8302 - val_loss: 0.7352 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 19/20
5/5 [==============================] - 25s 5s/step - loss: 0.6670 - accuracy: 0.8113 - val_loss: 0.7374 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 20/20
5/5 [==============================] - 24s 5s/step - loss: 0.6534 - accuracy: 0.8302 - val_loss: 0.7399 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
2/2 [==============================] - 1s 314ms/step - loss: 0.7171 - accuracy: 0.4167
Accuracy: 41.67%
```

Summarizing: High loss, but decrease very slowly. Accuracy is varying, but in the end it stabilizes at the same value (usually 0,7925 or 0,8113). And my accuracy for the validation set don't even respond to any changes that occur with the other metrics.

My main concern is the validation data is not behaving as it should. I already tried changing the optimizers, activation functions of every layer, weight initializers, number of epochs (went till 100 several times but nothing changed), batch size, shuffling the data using Keras function and Python built-in method, and so on.

The only thing I did not tried was to change the input shapes, but, as I mentioned earlier, this was the only way I got the 3D array to be accepted in the Input Layer.

If you guys have any tips to what can be changed to achieve more consistent results, I would be very grateful.

Any additional commentary will be happily accepted.

This is my first question here and I am not a native english speaker, so sorry if any information was not very clear.

Cheers, Matheus Zimmermann.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply to_categorical method or One hot encoding approach to the
y_train , y_val and y_test variables.
Hope than after applying it ,you will find your validation accuracy perfectly.
I faced this type of same problem before.